# Link Label Referer

Tags: c#, wordpress

I have a word press site and I use the JetPack plugin to keep track of hits to my blog. It also informs me the referrer from where the users came form.

Since the blog is about my C# application it would be great to know how many people have visited my site via links on my application.

I have a many link labels and urls embedded in rich-text boxes. How would I get the application as a referrer and display in the Jetpack?

C#

```
private void blog_LinkClicked(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.website.com");
}
```

I thought at first I'd have the links going to a blank webpage that will then redirect them. However, I have multiple links and the links are changed via a database on a regular database...

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.